# How to retrieve texts in table?

Tags: web-scraping, rust

I'm trying to get texts in from the table below

The texts I want to get are ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE"]

```html
    <div class="inner">
        <table class="table_class">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <dl>
                        <dt>AAA</dt>
                        <dd class="desc">ONE</dd>
                    </dl>
                </td>
            
                <td>
                    <dl>
                        <dt>BBB</dt>
                        <dd>TWO</dd>
                    </dl>
                </td>
            
                <td>
                    <dl>
                        <dt>CCC</dt>
                        <dd class="level4_2">THREE</dd>
                    </dl>
                </td>
            
                <td>
                    <dl>
                        <dt>DDDD</dt>
                        <dd>FOUR</dd>
                    </dl>
                </td>
            </tr>
                <td>
                    <dl>
                        <dt>EEEE</dt>
                        <dd class="level5_1">FIVE</dd>
                    </dl>
                </td>
            </tr>
            
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

I tried once like codes below but the nodes are empty..

I'm not sure how to retrieve the informations I want correctly

Thanks in advance

```rust
let document = Html::parse_document(&body);

let stats = Selector::parse("div.inner > table > tbody > tr > td > dl > dd").unwrap();
let mut stats_element = document.select(&stats).collect::<Vec<_>>();

let first_stat = stats_element .text().collect::<Vec<_>>()[0]
    .trim()
    .to_string();
```

Comment: Are you using [the `scraper` crate](https://docs.rs/scraper/latest/scraper/)?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
let document = Html::parse_document(&body);

let stats = Selector::parse("div.inner > table > tbody > tr > td > dl > dd").unwrap();

for stats_element in document.select(&stats) {
    for text in stats_element.text() {
        println!("{:?}", text);
    }
}
```

The following [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) methods are likely to be useful here: `map`, `flat_map`, `filter`. [`impl FromIterator for Result<A, E>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html#impl-FromIterator%3CResult%3CA%2C%20E%3E%3E) and [`Itertools::exactly_one`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.exactly_one) may also be useful.

Comment: Thanks! I tried but I think the length of document.select(&stats) is zero? but when I typed same query in dev console using `document.querySelectorAll("div.inner> table > tbody > tr > td > dl > dd")` it gave me exact nodes I want. Is it possible that scraper crate doesn't recognize this query properly? Other queries work fine except table one so far